# MapKit mapView:viewForAnnotation has no effect on pin color

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I can't seem to change the pin color.

I have my view controller extend `<MKMapViewDelegate>` and implement `mapView:viewForAnnotation`  I'm close but must be missing something.  any help would be appreciated.

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "StopAnnotation.h"

#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize mapView=_mapView;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 43.066667;
    zoomLocation.longitude = -89.4;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, METERS_PER_MILE, METERS_PER_MILE);

    MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [_mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

    [_mapView setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:[[StopAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:zoomLocation]];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pav = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    pav.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    return pav;
}

// the rest of the methods are default, i.e. viewDid* and shouldAutorotate*, etc...
```

**StopAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface StopAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c;
@end
```

**StopAnnotation.m**

```
#import "StopAnnotation.h"

@implementation StopAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return @"subtitle";
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return @"title";
}

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c {
    coordinate = c;
    NSLog(@"%f,%f", c.latitude, c.longitude);
    return self;
}

@end
```

I'm doing an exercise & the code was mostly from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial)

Thanks!!

Comment: @jbat100 yea they're still red :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set MainViewController as the delegate of mapView, ie if you are not then the map view might be generating default pins, if you put a breakpoint in

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

does it actually get called?

Comment: You're right. it doesn't seem to get called. How would I go about setting the delegate (and in which class)?

Comment: haha I did it within the storyboard & it works! Thanks a bunch! Is the storyboard data ever written in code or just internal data?

Comment: in MainViewController viewDidLoad: set the delegate by doing mapView.delegate = self; You need to declare MainViewController as confroming to the MKMapViewDelegate protocol to silence compiler warnings.

Comment: _mapView.delegate = self; would have fixed it